# Expand number range to the individual numbers with NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, na

This question is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61369441/expand-number-range-to-the-individual-numbers).

Say that I have an NA:

```
df <- data.frame(start = c(10, 20), end = c(15,NA), label = c('ex1','ex2'))
```

When I use the following code:

```
df[, seq(.SD[['start']], .SD[['end']]), by = label]
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , seq(.SD[["start"]], .SD[["end"]]), by = label) : 
  unused argument (by = label)
```

How do I get something like this?:

```
label V1
 1:   ex1 10
 2:   ex1 11
 3:   ex1 12
 4:   ex1 13
 5:   ex1 14
 6:   ex1 15
 7:   ex2 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fcoalesce` to replace the `NA` values in `end` with the `start` value and create a sequence from `start` to `end` for each `label`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df <- df[!(is.na(start) & is.na(end))]
df[, end := fcoalesce(end, start)]
df[, seq(start, end), by = label]

#   label V1
#1:   ex1 10
#2:   ex1 11
#3:   ex1 12
#4:   ex1 13
#5:   ex1 14
#6:   ex1 15
#7:   ex2 20
```

Or using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!(is.na(start) & is.na(end))) %>%
  mutate(end = coalesce(end, start)) %>%
  group_by(label) %>%
  summarise(num = seq(start, end), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: This is wonderful. How do I do it if I have NAs for both start and end?

Comment: What do you want to do when you have `NA`'s in `start` as well as `end` ?

Comment: Drop the entry.

Comment: You can drop such rows first with `df <- df[!(is.na(start) & is.na(end))]` before using `fcoalesce` code.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it dplyr?